# Why can't I change the instance variable inside this session.dataTask()?

Tags: swift

I tried to directly get the data recieved from a URLsession updated into the instance variables. Tried the code below in playgroud, I can see until the `self.cityName = weatherdecoded.name` the code seems working fine, but the `self.cityName` which intended to be the instance's variable didn't got updated. The results are `nil`s. Hope to understand the reason, what is the mistake i made. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
class WeatherManager {
    var cityName: String?
    var conditionID: Int?
    var temp: Double?


    func fetchData(cityName: String) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let urlStr = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid=8da179fa1c83749056ec6a5385cabb04&q=" + cityName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        print(urlStr)
        let url = URL(string: urlStr)!

        let weatherDataSession = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: getdata(data:response:error:))
        weatherDataSession.resume()
    }

    func getdata(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            if let safedata = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                   let weatherdecoded = try decoder.decode(Weatherdata.self, from: safedata)

                    self.cityName = weatherdecoded.name
                    self.conditionID = weatherdecoded.weather[0].id
                    self.temp = weatherdecoded.main.temp

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
}

struct Weatherdata: Decodable {
    let weather : [Weather]
    let main: Main
    let name: String
}

struct Weather: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let description: String
}

struct Main: Decodable {
    let temp: Double
}

let weathermanager = WeatherManager()
weathermanager.fetchData(cityName: "beijing")

print(weathermanager.cityName)
print(weathermanager.conditionID)
print(weathermanager.temp)
```

Comment: `URLSession.dataTask` is asynchronous. Start with reading about asynchronous execution and completion handlers in Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple reason is the fact that you are printing the values before the request actually completes. You have to use a completion handler:

```
class WeatherManager {
    func fetchObject<T: Decodable>(urlPath: String, onCompletion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let url = URL(string: urlPath)!

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                onCompletion(.failure(error))
                return
            }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
               let decoded = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data ?? Data())
                onCompletion(.success(decoded))
            } catch {
                onCompletion(.failure(error))
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }


    func fetchWeather(cityName: String, onCompletion: @escaping (Result<Weatherdata, Error>) -> Void) {
        let urlPath = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid=8da179fa1c83749056ec6a5385cabb04&q=" + cityName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

        fetchObject(urlPath: urlPath, onCompletion: onCompletion)
    }
}

struct Weatherdata: Decodable {
    let weather : [Weather]
    let main: Main
    let name: String
}

struct Weather: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let description: String
}

struct Main: Decodable {
    let temp: Double
}

let weathermanager = WeatherManager()
weathermanager.fetchWeather(cityName: "beijing") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let weatherData):
        print(weatherData.name)
        print(weatherData.weather[0].id)
        print(weatherData.main.temp)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```